# sharepoint online REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

Is it possible to use sharepoint 2013 REST API, documented there:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

On a Sharepoint Online site ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes absolutely, it is even preferred :)

Comment: can we use access token from 

https://api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me/services

for sharepoint?